# Joining the subtitles with text body of article using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the body text of the article which is in p class with subtitles that is in span class but I'm not sure how can I join them(both body text and subtitles). I have joined the body text but subtitles are missing. Im using python and beautiful soup
This is the sample [link](https://www.eltiempo.com/mundo/eeuu-y-canada/los-secretos-revelados-de-melania-trump-en-libro-de-stephanie-grisham-622637)
Here is how I join the text

```
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  respone_html = response.read().decode()
  parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(respone_html, 'html.parser')
  page_text = ''
  if parsed_html.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'articulo-contenido'}) is not None:
   texts = parsed_html.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'articulo-contenido'})
  for text in texts:
       textbody = text.findAll('p',attrs={'class' : 'contenido'})
       textsubtitle = text.findAll('span',attrs={'class' : 'articulo-subtitulo'})
       for p in textbody:
             page_text += '\n' + ''.join(p.findAll(text = True))
```

The output Im getting is the only body text like this

> Stephanie Grisham, quien trabajó durante cinco años en diferentes
> roles como asesora principal de Donald y Melania Trump, cuenta sus
> memorias de aquella época en su libro 'I'll Take Your Questions Now'
> (responderé sus preguntas ahora).(Puede leer: EE. UU. teme una
> 'subversión electoral' con Trump coqueteando con volver). El relato se
> publicará el próximo martes, 5 de octubre. Sin embargo, 'CNN' obtuvo
> una copia anticipada y reveló algunas descripciones que realiza
> Grisham acerca de Melania Trump, quien, para muchos, es la primera
> dama más reservada de la historia política estadounidense moderna.
> Cabe resaltar que Grisham trabajó como directora de comunicaciones y
> jefa de personal de la exprimera dama, por lo que sabe varios de sus
> detalles más íntimos.De hecho, 'The Washington Post' se comunicó con
> la oficina de Melania Trump para preguntar sobre el libro, la cual
> afirmó lo siguiente en una declaración: "La intención detrás de este
> libro es obvia. Es un intento de redimirse después de un mal desempeño
> como secretaria de prensa, relaciones personales fallidas y
> comportamiento poco profesional en la Casa Blanca. A través de la
> falsedad y la traición busca ganar relevancia y dinero a expensas de
> la señora Trump".(Lea también: Trump tuvo un asistente llamado 'el
> hombre de la música' para calmar su ira).Ahora bien, a continuación
> podrá saber cinco cosas que se exponen el libro de Grisham sobre la
> exprimera dama: Aunque cuando vivía en la Casa Blanca Melania no era
> muy expresiva en cuanto a los comentarios que hacían sobre ella,
> Grisham comenta que la esposa del expresidente solía leer lo que la
> prensa escribía sobre ella. "Como su esposo y todos sus hijos, la Sra.
> Trump escudriñó sus recortes de prensa como un arquitecto experto que
> se enfoca en planos. No se le pasó por alto ningún detalle, no pasó
> nada por alto. Tenía las alertas de Google configuradas para ella y lo
> vio todo", escribió la autora del libro.(De interés: Trump demanda a
> su sobrina y al NY Times por investigación sobre finanzas). Grisham
> comentó que Melania no pasaba mucho tiempo en la espaciosa 'suite' que
> se le asignó, sino que solía trabajar desde su casa, mucho antes de
> que el covid-19 estuviera presente. Incluso, el Servicio Secreto la
> llamaba 'Rapunzel' porque permanecía "en su torre"."Teníamos reuniones
> en persona, pero por lo general se llevaban a cabo en la sala de mapas
> frente a los ascensores a la residencia. Allí planificaríamos los
> horarios, responderíamos a consultas urgentes y discutiríamos los
> objetivos", afirmó Grisham.La autora dijo, adicionalmente, que la
> exprimera dama dedicaba mucho tiempo a su cuidado personal: "Ella
> creía que la relajación era fundamental para el régimen de belleza de
> uno, al igual que, por supuesto, los tratamientos de spa y
> faciales".(Además: Donald Trump quiso pintar su avión para que se
> pareciera al presidencial). De acuerdo con Grisham, había tensión
> entre la esposa y la hija de Donald Trump porque Ivanka, quien era
> llamada por su madrastra como 'la princesa', tenía el deseo de ser el
> centro de atención en los eventos públicos y viajes.Según el escrito
> de la exasesora, Melania era una estudiante de protocolo y solía ser
> muy rigurosa en cuanto a respetar las tradiciones de los países que
> son reservadas solo para un presidente y su cónyuge, no para la hija
> del mandatario y su esposo. Cuando en 2018 se divulgaron las
> acusaciones de infidelidad de Donald Trump con la actriz porno Stormy
> Daniels y la exmodelo de 'Playboy' Karen MacDougal, se dice que
> Melania tomó una caravana separada para llegar al discurso del Estado
> de la Unión de ese año. Sin embargo, esta información no se
> confirmó.No obstante, Grisham dijo que la mujer sí estaba enojada con
> su esposo y no quiso exponerse públicamente junto a él."Sentí que la
> señora Trump estaba avergonzada, y que quería que él también se
> sintiera avergonzado. No sé si él es capaz de eso o no", escribió
> Grisham.(Le recomendamos: Capitolio de EE. UU., en alerta por
> manifestación de partidarios de Trump). En 2018, la exprimera dama
> apareció con una chaqueta verde que decía en la espalda 'Realmente no
> me importa. ¿A ti?',  durante una visita a un centro de detención de
> Texas. Según cuenta la exasesora, posiblemente Melania no sabía las
> críticas que iba a recibir por el mensaje de la chaqueta justo cuando
> acudía a una causa preocupante para el país en ese momento.Grisham
> aseguró, además, que el entonces presidente Donald Trump parecía
> molesto por la situación y miro a su esposa para decirle: "¿Qué
> diablos estabas pensando?". (Siga leyendo: General de EE.UU. alertó a
> China sobre la salud mental de Trump, dice libro).ELTIEMPO.COM

but it should have headings like

Stephanie Grisham, quien trabajó durante cinco años en diferentes roles como asesora principal de Donald y Melania Trump, cuenta sus memorias de aquella época en su libro 'I'll Take Your Questions Now' (responderé sus preguntas ahora).(Puede leer: EE. UU. teme una 'subversión electoral' con Trump coqueteando con volver).
El relato se publicará el próximo martes, 5 de octubre. Sin embargo, 'CNN' obtuvo una copia anticipada y reveló algunas descripciones que realiza Grisham acerca de Melania Trump, quien, para muchos, es la primera dama más reservada de la historia política estadounidense moderna. Cabe resaltar que Grisham trabajó como directora de comunicaciones y jefa de personal de la exprimera dama, por lo que sabe varios de sus detalles más íntimos.De hecho, 'The Washington Post' se comunicó con la oficina de Melania Trump para preguntar sobre el libro, la cual afirmó lo siguiente en una declaración: "La intención detrás de este libro es obvia. Es un intento de redimirse después de un mal desempeño como secretaria de prensa, relaciones personales fallidas y comportamiento poco profesional en la Casa Blanca. A través de la falsedad y la traición busca ganar relevancia y dinero a expensas de la señora Trump".(Lea también: Trump tuvo un asistente llamado 'el hombre de la música' para calmar su ira).Ahora bien, a continuación podrá saber cinco cosas que se exponen el libro de Grisham sobre la exprimera dama:

**Leía su propia prensa**

Aunque cuando vivía en la Casa Blanca Melania no era muy expresiva en cuanto a los comentarios que hacían sobre ella, Grisham comenta que la esposa del expresidente solía leer lo que la prensa escribía sobre ella. "Como su esposo y todos sus hijos, la Sra. Trump escudriñó sus recortes de prensa como un arquitecto experto que se enfoca en planos. No se le pasó por alto ningún detalle, no pasó nada por alto. Tenía las alertas de Google configuradas para ella y lo vio todo", escribió la autora del libro.(De interés: Trump demanda a su sobrina y al NY Times por investigación sobre finanzas).

**Estaba fuera de su oficina**

Grisham comentó que Melania no pasaba mucho tiempo en la espaciosa 'suite' que se le asignó, sino que solía trabajar desde su casa, mucho antes de que el covid-19 estuviera presente. Incluso, el Servicio Secreto la llamaba 'Rapunzel' porque permanecía "en su torre"."Teníamos reuniones en persona, pero por lo general se llevaban a cabo en la sala de mapas frente a los ascensores a la residencia. Allí planificaríamos los horarios, responderíamos a consultas urgentes y discutiríamos los objetivos", afirmó Grisham.La autora dijo, adicionalmente, que la exprimera dama dedicaba mucho tiempo a su cuidado personal: "Ella creía que la relajación era fundamental para el régimen de belleza de uno, al igual que, por supuesto, los tratamientos de spa y faciales".(Además: Donald Trump quiso pintar su avión para que se pareciera al presidencial).
La relación entre Melania e Ivanka Trump
De acuerdo con Grisham, había tensión entre la esposa y la hija de Donald Trump porque Ivanka, quien era llamada por su madrastra como 'la princesa', tenía el deseo de ser el centro de atención en los eventos públicos y viajes.Según el escrito de la exasesora, Melania era una estudiante de protocolo y solía ser muy rigurosa en cuanto a respetar las tradiciones de los países que son reservadas solo para un presidente y su cónyuge, no para la hija del mandatario y su esposo.

**Rumores de infidelidad**

Cuando en 2018 se divulgaron las acusaciones de infidelidad de Donald Trump con la actriz porno Stormy Daniels y la exmodelo de 'Playboy' Karen MacDougal, se dice que Melania tomó una caravana separada para llegar al discurso del Estado de la Unión de ese año. Sin embargo, esta información no se confirmó.No obstante, Grisham dijo que la mujer sí estaba enojada con su esposo y no quiso exponerse públicamente junto a él."Sentí que la señora Trump estaba avergonzada, y que quería que él también se sintiera avergonzado. No sé si él es capaz de eso o no", escribió Grisham.(Le recomendamos: Capitolio de EE. UU., en alerta por manifestación de partidarios de Trump).

**Melania y la chaqueta**

En 2018, la exprimera dama apareció con una chaqueta verde que decía en la espalda 'Realmente no me importa. ¿A ti?',  durante una visita a un centro de detención de Texas. Según cuenta la exasesora, posiblemente Melania no sabía las críticas que iba a recibir por el mensaje de la chaqueta justo cuando acudía a una causa preocupante para el país en ese momento.Grisham aseguró, además, que el entonces presidente Donald Trump parecía molesto por la situación y miro a su esposa para decirle: "¿Qué diablos estabas pensando?".
(Siga leyendo: General de EE.UU. alertó a China sobre la salud mental de Trump, dice libro).ELTIEMPO.COM

Comment: Can you give us what you are getting after running this script? And what you should get ideally?

Comment: @TonyMontana I made the edits to include the output please have a look

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
text = parsed_html.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'articulo-contenido'}).div
for child in text.children:
    if not child.name:
        continue
    elif child.name=='p' and 'contenido' in child.attrs['class']:
        page_text += '\n' + child.text
    elif child.name=='span' and 'articulo-subtitulo' in child.attrs['class']:
        page_text += '\n\n' + child.text
         
print(page_text)
```

if you catch your elements by chunks (catch all subtitles, catch all paragraphs), you won't be able to put them back into their flow. "go with the flow"

Comment: I will check and let you know @diggusbickus